# How to repair a burnt PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, repair, pcb-layers

I'm trying to fix a burnt blender PCB(due to short circuiting). I have tried to trace copper traces on the PCB and wondering if i Should cut off the burnt area and redesign the affected PCB or use a jumper? (Affected area has a heat sink + transistor [image: How the PCB layout loos like])

[image: How it looks like above the Board]

Comment: Give that PCB a good isopropanol scrub, then cut and glue new copper traces where they are missing. You’ll be violating most safety standards by now. I would think about some conformal coating or hot melt clue to make the tracs not fall off. Is the device grounded?

Comment: It uses Ac voltage mostly....Ive managed to obtain a replica of the PCB and expecting it to work cz the design is simple and uses passive components

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is give the PCB a good clean, to try and remove as much of the carbonised buildup as possible.

Then I would start testing, if parts of the PCB have become conductive it may be necessary to cut slots or re-route signals using wires to fix that.

The good news is it seems your PCB already has a bunch of slots in it and the damage looks mostly superficial to me. I think there is a good chance after cleaning that the PCB itself will be fine.

Comment: Actually,wat worries me is I can't properly trace the burnt place. Has a hole.

Comment: You can't trace anything with all that crap on the PCB, give it a good scrubbing with IPA and then re-evaluate. Once the crap is gone I expect you will be able to fairly easilly tell the difference between places where there was never a track and places where a track has gone pyrotechnic.

Comment: Its buggered already. You aren't going to make it more buggered. Always worth giving it a go, and remember Big Fails are still Big - you got half way there!

Answer (score 0):

1) analyze fault, root cause
2) make it better than original if necessary or replace it

In order to prevent reoccurence, you need to be familiar with the Root Cause of this fault. 4 choices;

a) Bad Design
b) Bad Process
c) Bad Part
d) Bad User ( lack of cleaning)

Pick one then decide best approach.

A quick view of the photo tells me the section has creepage air gaps to isolate high voltage in the presence of surface moisture... but not dust bunnies that can bridge the gap.  So make the gap 2mm instead of 1~1.5? with a dremmel-like tool (thin cutter disc) Then clean and bridge conductors with suitable wire.

Then cross your fingers.

A quick analysis tells it it "may" be a toss-up between a) and d) for the harsh grease, and smoke cooking environment it is intended to work in.

The big semiconductor on the heat sink is probably a >=15A Triac, which may be damaged.

I would grind out the bad PCB around the gaps to leave a 2mm air gap using a Dremel router.  [image]

**It is also most likely an obsolete circuit board.**
 [image]

Honey , I have a problem.

Comment: It's actually the circuitry for a "previously working" Signature blender(difficult to find the manufacturer)

Comment: some members have no sense of humor (-1) and lack wisdom and experience .